# how to use python to detect and match lines in the imagesw?

Tags: python

I want to detect and match lines by using lsd and lbd in python, but I do not find the functions.

I use the opencv-python to do it, but do not find.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I try to use cv2.createLineSegmentDetector to detect the lines, but have no idea about match the deteced lines

Comment: Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).